# how to write java code of the json

Tags: android, arrays

I want to convert JSON into java code.  My jsoncode as per given below.

```
{
"nodes": [
    {
        "node": {
            "Name": "rahul Patel",
            "Address": "\n\tAhmedabad",
            "Date of Birth": "1991-05-03",
            "Occupation": "developer",
            "Member Since": "3 weeks 4 days"
        }
    }
]
```

java code

```
try {
            JSONObject objResponse = new JSONObject(strResponse);

            JSONArray jsonnodes = objResponse
                    .getJSONArray(nodes);


            System.out.println("=hello this is DoinBackground");
            for (i = 0; i < jsonnodes.length(); i++) {

                System.out.println("hello this is for loop of DoinBackground");
                JSONObject jsonnode = jsonnodes.getJSONObject(i);

                JSONObject jsonnodevalue = jsonnode
                        .getJSONObject(node);

                bean = new UserProfileBean();

                bean.name = jsonnodevalue.getString(Name);


                listActivities.add(bean);

            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

Here in logcat I print the value of before for loop `System.out.println("=hello this is DoinBackground");`,but value can't print under the for loop `System.out.println("hello this is for loop of DoinBackground");`

NOTE: Please let me know, Is it possible that we cannot used for loop in the code ? if yes then give the solution for that, There is another solution for this given problem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your json string is wrong. It must be trminated with `}`. Fix this and it will work.

**Fixed json string:**

```
{
    "nodes": [
        {
            "node": {
                "Name": "rahul Patel",
                "Address": "\n\tAhmedabad",
                "Date of Birth": "1991-05-03",
                "Occupation": "developer",
                "Member Since": "3 weeks 4 days"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

**Sample code to test:**

```
String j = "{\r\n" + 
        "    \"nodes\": [\r\n" + 
        "        {\r\n" + 
        "            \"node\": {\r\n" + 
        "                \"Name\": \"rahul Patel\",\r\n" + 
        "                \"Address\": \"\\n\\tAhmedabad\",\r\n" + 
        "                \"Date of Birth\": \"1991-05-03\",\r\n" + 
        "                \"Occupation\": \"developer\",\r\n" + 
        "                \"Member Since\": \"3 weeks 4 days\"\r\n" + 
        "            }\r\n" + 
        "        }\r\n" + 
        "    ]\r\n" + 
        "}";

try{
    JSONObject objResponse = new JSONObject(j);

    JSONArray jsonnodes = objResponse.getJSONArray("nodes" );

    for (int i = 0; i < jsonnodes.length(); i++) {

        JSONObject jsonnode = jsonnodes.getJSONObject(i);

        JSONObject jsonnodevalue = jsonnode
                .getJSONObject("node");

        Log.v("name", jsonnodevalue.getString("Name"));
        Log.v("address", jsonnodevalue.getString("Address"));
        Log.v("occupation", jsonnodevalue.getString("Occupation"));
    }

}
catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Thanks,
Is it possible without for loop?

Comment: its possible but not recommended, because Arrays are always better accessed through loops. However, you may use `while` loop instead of `for` loop but i think it won't make any difference in your case. But if you know that you'll always gonna get one object in array then you may skip array by simply using the index value for e.g. `JSONObject jsonnode = jsonnodes.getJSONObject(0);`

Comment: @RahulPatel ya its possible but if we are multiple elements in json that time this for loop will be use. and For single item we can do it without for loop

Comment: @Waqas Thanks. you give the exact solution for my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try using Gson - http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/. Will save a lot of headache.

In your code, however make sure that your JSON string is being parsed properly. 
Just to be sure `objResponse.getJSONArray(nodes)` should be `objResponse.getJSONArray("nodes")`

Comment: Thanks,
Please let me know in logcat why it is not display after for loop.